# Recurrence relation for Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind

Tags: recurrence-relations, chebyshev-polynomials

I tried to derive recurrence relation for Chebyshev polynomials from their generating function
$$\frac{1-xt}{1-2xt+t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}T_{n}(x)t^n.$$
I've differentiated both sides with respect to t to obtain:
$$\frac{x-t}{(1-2tx+t^2)^{3/2}}-\frac{x(1-t^2)}{(1-2tx+t^2)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{n}(x)nt^{n-1}.$$I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
T_n( \cos( \theta))= \cos(n \theta).
\end{eqnarray*}
...
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} T_n( \cos( \theta)) t^n &=&  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos(n \theta) t^n \\
&=& \Re \left(  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ( e^{i \theta} t) ^n  ) \right) \\
&=& \Re \left(  \frac{1}{(1- e^{i \theta} t) } \right) \\
&=& \Re \left(  \frac{1-e^{-i \theta}t}{(1- e^{i \theta} t)(1-e^{-i \theta}t) } \right) \\
&=& \Re \left(  \frac{1-e^{-i \theta}t}{1- 2\cos(\theta)t+t^2  }  \right)\\
&=&   \frac{1-\cos(\theta) t}{1- 2\cos(\theta)t+t^2 }.  \\
\end{eqnarray*}